# Embed more data into enum cases

Tags: ios, swift, enums, set, uifont

I have the following imbricated enums.

```
public enum Icons {
    public enum Arrow: String {
        case Angle1 = "\u{f100}"
        case Angle2 = "\u{f101}"
        case Angle3 = "\u{f102}"
        case Angle4 = "\u{f103}"
        case ArrowBottomLeft = "\u{f104}"
        case ArrowBottomRight = "\u{f105}"
    }

    public enum Clothing: String {
        case BallCap = "\u{f100}"
        case Belt = "\u{f101}"
        case Boot = "\u{f102}"
        case BowTie = "\u{f103}"
    }

    public enum Emotions: String {
        case Angel = "\u{f100}"
        case AngrySick = "\u{f101}"
        case Angry = "\u{f102}"
        case Bitter = "\u{f103}"
        case Concerned = "\u{f104}"
        case Cool = "\u{f105}"
    }
}
```

I have a huge collection of icons which I want to integrate in my app. I also have an UIImage extension initializer which takes a UIFont as parameter and a string for the icon to be drawn (originating from `Icons.Category.Icons` - note that in this case Category is either Arrow, Clothing or Emotions).

To get an icon I call:

```
let image = UIImage(  
                      fromIcon: Icons.Emotions.Angel.rawValue, 
                      withFont: UIFont.iconFontAngel(22)
                   )
```

Each of the three types of icons has an associated UIFont extension:

- Arrow type has `UIFont.iconFontArrow(size)`
- Clothing type has `UIFont.iconFontClothing(size)`
- Emotions type has `UIFont.iconFontEmotions(size)`

How can I declare the Icons better to include UIFont, size for the font and other category specific options, since I know exactly what UIFont corresponds to each category and I only have to pass a single parameter such as `Icons.Arrow.Angle3` to the UIImage initializer and extract from this parameter type the string, UIFont and other needed options?

I was thinking about declaring the icons type as set but I'm not sure how to resolve this in a clean manner.

Comment: You can use a struct with the imbricated enum and a size value, if you want to include a size. As is, you can use introspection to determine which UIFont to use. For example (`let icon = Icons.Arrow.Angle3; icon is Icons.Clothing //will return true while; icon is Icons.Emotions //will return false`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use an enum for this. Use a struct.

```
public struct FontBasedIcon {

    private init(string: String, fontName: String) {
        self.string = string
        self.fontName = fontName
    }

    public let string: String
    public let fontName: String

    public func font(size size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: size)!
    }

    public func image(fontSize fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let string = self.string as NSString
        let attributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: self.font(size: fontSize) ]
        var rect = string.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(CGFloat.infinity, CGFloat.infinity), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
        let size = CGSizeMake(ceil(rect.width), ceil(rect.height))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        string.drawAtPoint(CGPoint.zero, withAttributes: attributes)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }

}
```

Then declare your constants as static properties:

```
public extension FontBasedIcon {
    public struct Arrow {
        public static let Angle1 = FontBasedIcon(string: "\u{f100}", fontName: "ArrowFont")
        public static let Angle2 = FontBasedIcon(string: "\u{f101}", fontName: "ArrowFont")
        // etc.
    }

    public struct Emotion {
        public static let Angel = FontBasedIcon(string: "\u{f100}", fontName: "EmotionFont")
        public static let AngrySick = FontBasedIcon(string: "\u{f101}", fontName: "EmotionFont")
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let angelImage = FontBasedIcon.Emotion.Angel.image(fontSize: 22)
```